# Cplex string, i am trying to call a string inside a string in cplex

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

Please I’m new to cplex, so my input data is a string of 240hours but I want cplex to read it for every 24 hours each. How do i do that please?
E.g. L= {L1,L2,L3 to 24}
And i want dexpr float to execute for total “L” but should go for “L1,L2 etc.

On the sheetreed, i tried ‘L from sheetsread(wins,”L1”,”L2”,”L3”…to “L10”, but i got an opl error

Comment: I encourage you to read the 240 hours and then do whatever you need in OPL to turn that into what you need later on